# Using phase information to extract sample values

Tags: discrete-signals, phase

I have **one cycle** of the following signal stored in a memory:

```
 x(n)=sin(2 * pi * n/N + theta)

 where  theta= 2*pi*q/N and q, N are integers.
```

How do I use these values to obtain sinusoides (samples) with same frequency but different phase?

Answer (score 2):

If the values are stored in a linear array indexed by $n$, read the values out 
sequentially from a *different* starting point in the array, that is beginning with a *nonzero* value of $n$, and have the read out "wrap" around the end of the array, that
is, the incrementing of the index is done *modulo* $N$. This gives sinusoids
with possible initial
phases $0, 2\pi/N, (2)2\pi/N, (3)2\pi/N, \ldots, (N-1)2\pi/N$ depending on the
choice of starting point of the read out.  If you want other values
for the initial phase, you will need to do some computations, and not just
a plain reading out from memory.

Comment: +1. Just to expound on Dilip's last comment a bit, if you want fine-grained phase values that don't correspond exactly to your table indices (a common occurrence), you have two options: 1. increase your table size (you obviously have to stop somewhere) or 2. interpolate between values. If your table is large enough to begin with, then you should be able to get away with simple linear interpolation between points for most applications.